# Can Java GC items iterated past?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm

Let's say I have the following Java method:

```
private static void testLoop() throws Exception {
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0 ; i < 100000 ; i++)
        list.add(i);
    for (Integer a : list) {
        Thread.sleep(10000); // Simulate lots of work.
    }
}
```

**Question:** Will the JVM be able to garbage collect my integers once I've iteraded over them in the slow loop (since I will not reuse `list` for something else)?

Comment: I assume you're asking if the JVM will be able to garbage collect 50% of the integers once the iteration is half way through?

Comment: @aioobe - I think the OP is asking whether his list will be eligible for GC in the second loop (where list is not actually needed / used correctly)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, the `list` reference is still live (and thereby also the references to the integer objects). The JVM will not deduce that the list is half-way traversed and that some Integer objects will not be needed anymore.

If you want the objects to be eligible for garbage collection, you'll have to remove the references from the list, either completely or by replacing them by `null` (as @Brandon suggests in the comments):

```
ListIterator<Integer> iter = list.listIterator();
while (iter.hasNext()) {
    int i = itr.next();
    iter.set(null);      // or iter.remove() but that's O(n) instead of O(1)
    // process i
    Thread.sleep(10000); // Simulate lots of work.
}
```

Comment: If you want them to be garbage collected you need to remove them from the list.

Comment: Or replace them with `null` references.

Comment: @TheLostMind: If you remove them, generally _nothing_ is left behind.  Not even `null`. :P

Comment: @TheLostMind, Brandon still has a good point. `remove` on an `ArrayList` is O(n). Calling `set` is O(1).

Comment: @cHao - ya.. You are right. An `IndexOutOfBounds` will be thrown in case of `get()` if size < index

Comment: @aioobe - Agreed. Shifting elements is not advisable (`remove`). It is better to set values to `null` :)

Comment: This is correct for typical implementations, as long as we assume that no warm-up of the optimizer took place in this simple example, however, to be nitpicking, the entire method code has no effect that is visible to the outside (`Thread.sleep` is explicitly specified to have no memory consistency effects) so the garbage collector *can* collect all `Integer` objects together with the `ArrayList` once the optimizer has transformed the code to the equivalent of `Thread.sleep(10000 * 100000)`…

Comment: Even if you have objects with overridden `finalize` methods?

Answer (score 1):

Generally no.

But if you use something like this:

```
Iterator<Integer> itr = list.iterator();
Integer i;

while (itr.hasNext()) {
    i = itr.next();
    itr.remove();
    Thread.sleep(10000); // Simulate lots of work.
}
```

Gives more of change for the GC to clean up the used integers.

Comment: But won't this throw ConcurrentModficationException, since you are modifying list while iterating over it

Comment: Modification using the iterator won't throw the ConcurrentModificationException if supported. Please read the Java Doc on Iterators.